# GroovyShell and Binding.setVariable() for callable objects

Tags: groovy

I am experimenting with some dynamic variable creation with `GroovyShell` and encountered an issue. First, the working code:

```
static def defVar(def glob) {
    glob.setVariable('test', new Test())
}

class MyBinding extends Binding {
}

class Test {
    def call() {
        println("--- hello ---")
    }
}

Binding glob = new MyBinding()
GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(glob)
defVar(glob)
shell.parse('test()').run()
```

This gives me the expected output:

```
--- hello ---
```

However, I want to call `setVariable()` dynamically when `getVariable()` is called, something like this:

```
static def defVar(def glob) {
    glob.setVariable('test', new Test())
}

class MyBinding extends Binding {
    def getVariable(String name) {
        if (! hasVariable('test')) {
            BindingTest.defVar(this)
        }
        return super.getVariable(name)
    }
}

class Test {
    def call() {
        println("--- hello ---")
    }
}

Binding glob = new MyBinding()
GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(glob)
//defVar(glob)
shell.parse('test()').run()
```

But this fails with the below error:

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script1.test() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: getAt(java.lang.String), use([Ljava.lang.Object;), use(java.lang.Class, groovy.lang.Closure), use(java.util.List, groovy.lang.Closure), wait(), wait(long)
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script1.test() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: getAt(java.lang.String), use([Ljava.lang.Object;), use(java.lang.Class, groovy.lang.Closure), use(java.util.List, groovy.lang.Closure), wait(), wait(long)
    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:1)
    at Script1$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at BindingTest.run(BindingTest.groovy:23)
```

When I added tracing code like this:

```
class MyBinding extends Binding {
    def getVariable(String name) {
        if (! hasVariable(name)) {
            BindingTest.defVar(this)
        }
        println("getVariable: ${name}: ${super.getVariable(name).getClass().getName()}")
        return super.getVariable(name)
    }

    void setVariable (String name, def val) {
        println("setVariable: ${name}: ${val.getClass().getName()}")
        super.setVariable(name, val)
    }

    def getProperty(String name) {
        println("getProperty: ${name}: ${super.getProperty(name)}")
        return super.getProperty(name)
    }

    void setProperty (String name, def val) {
        println("setProperty: ${name}: ${val.getClass().getName()}")
        super.setProperty(name, val)
    }
}
```

In the working case, I get the below output:

```
setVariable: test: Test
--- hello ---
```

In the non-working case, I get this output:

```
setVariable: test: Test
getVariable: test: Test
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script1.test() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
...
```

Two questions:

1. In the working scenario, why is there no `getVariable`?
2. In the non-working scenario, why is the `Test` object returned by `getVariable` getting rejected?

Note that this issue is specific to callable values. If I set a simple value such as a string, to `test`, then both approaches work fine. E.g., with this sort of a change:

```
...
static def defVar(def glob) {
    glob.setVariable('test', '--- hello ---')
}
...
shell.parse('println(test)').run()
```

I get the below identical output with both approaches:

```
setVariable: test: java.lang.String
getVariable: test: java.lang.String
setVariable: test: java.lang.String
--- hello ---
```

Though, I am not sure why `setVariable` gets called twice. I couldn't find any documentation explaining these puzzling behaviors. Could anybody here shed some light on them?

*Please note, all the code snippets have been simplified for the ease of demonstrating the problem rather than for their intended purpose*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a property as a callable fallback, the `Binding.getVariable()` method does not get involved. This behavior is controlled by the metaclass, and in your case, it all drives to the execution of the `MetaClassImpl.invokePropertyOrMissing()` method. This method determines if

```
test()
```

should invoke `test.call()` (in case of an existing property), or should it fallback to the `missingMethod()` method. Here is what this method implementation looks like:

```java
private Object invokePropertyOrMissing(Object object, String methodName, Object[] originalArguments, boolean fromInsideClass, boolean isCallToSuper) {
    // if no method was found, try to find a closure defined as a field of the class and run it
    Object value = null;
    final MetaProperty metaProperty = this.getMetaProperty(methodName, false);
    if (metaProperty != null)
      value = metaProperty.getProperty(object);
    else {
        if (object instanceof Map)
          value = ((Map)object).get(methodName);
    }

    if (value instanceof Closure) {  // This test ensures that value != this If you ever change this ensure that value != this
        Closure closure = (Closure) value;
        MetaClass delegateMetaClass = closure.getMetaClass();
        return delegateMetaClass.invokeMethod(closure.getClass(), closure, CLOSURE_DO_CALL_METHOD, originalArguments, false, fromInsideClass);
    }

    if (object instanceof Script) {
        Object bindingVar = ((Script) object).getBinding().getVariables().get(methodName);
        if (bindingVar != null) {
            MetaClass bindingVarMC = ((MetaClassRegistryImpl) registry).getMetaClass(bindingVar);
            return bindingVarMC.invokeMethod(bindingVar, CLOSURE_CALL_METHOD, originalArguments);
        }
    }
    return invokeMissingMethod(object, methodName, originalArguments, null, isCallToSuper);
}
```

<sup>Source: https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_2_5_X/src/main/groovy/groovy/lang/MetaClassImpl.java#L1262-L1287</sup>

Now, pay attention to the branch `if (object instanceof Script)` and how the binding variable gets retrieved. It tries to retrieve `test` variable from binding object using:

```java
Object bindingVar = ((Script) object).getBinding().getVariables().get(methodName);
```

Your code would work if it was:

```java
Object bindingVar = ((Script) object).getBinding().getVariable(methodName);
```

instead. But it's not.

You can make your second case working if you override `getVariables()` method instead of `getVariable(String name)`, for instance:

```
class MyBinding extends Binding {
    @Override
    Map getVariables() {
        return super.getVariables() + [
                test: new Test()
        ]
    }
}
```

Of course, your final implementation might be much more sophisticated. (E.g. you could get `super.getVariables()` map first, check which variables are missing and add a default variable only if the initial map was missing given variable.) But this is up to you.

Alternatively, consider using `methodMissing` instead of the binding variable fallback. It could make your code much easier to read and reason about.

Comment: Szymon, can't understand why `shell.parse('println "smth" \n test()').run()` works in first non-working example

Comment: @daggett It works when you add `println`, because `println` method in the `groovy.lang.Script` class invokes `getProperty("out")`, which in this case adds `test` to the binding variables. (Any invocation of `getProperty()` or `getVariable()` methods initializes the default values in the binding variables in this example.) Here is a related source code: https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_2_5_X/src/main/groovy/groovy/lang/Script.java#L152

Comment: Thank you, for the pointer to the underlying *magic*. With the information you provided, I was able to construct a custom `Map` with an overridden `get()` for detecting the missing variable and setting it dynamically and it worked well.